# OpenCV stitching_detailed.cpp Assertion Failed error

Tags: c++, opencv

I've asked this question on the OpenCV Answers site but haven't received a response so thought I'd try here instead.

I've just built opencv 3.2.0 and opencv_contrib 3.2.0, all successfully, and now I'm using the [stitching_detailed.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) sample file to try out some stuff (using the `--try_cuda=yes` option), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Finding features...
Features in image #1: 217
Features in image #2: 224
Features in image #3: 281
Features in image #4: 235
Features in image #5: 172
Finding features, time: 3.58099 sec
Pairwise matchingPairwise matching, time: 2.84527 sec
Initial camera intrinsics #2:
K:
[1012.630229401095, 0, 447;
 0, 1012.630229401095, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[0.96701878, 0.020416204, 0.012416624;
 0.014757388, 0.97670352, 0.26495183;
 0.046871029, 0.11209502, 1]
Initial camera intrinsics #3:
K:
[1012.630229401095, 0, 447;
 0, 1012.630229401095, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[1, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]
Initial camera intrinsics #4:
K:
[1012.630229401095, 0, 447;
 0, 1012.630229401095, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[1.0235587, -0.024432728, -0.014125917;
 0.004413465, 1.0243349, -0.26835808;
 -0.010042391, -0.15711401, 1.0413489]
Initial camera intrinsics #5:
K:
[1012.630229401095, 0, 447;
 0, 1012.630229401095, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[1.045368, -0.054304995, -0.018363208;
 0.013821163, 1.0776026, -0.54379475;
 -0.044207353, -0.2462063, 1.1049906]
Camera #2:
K:
[8478.069673382501, 0, 447;
 0, 8478.069673382501, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[0.9999181, 0.01271866, 0.001412834;
 -0.012757109, 0.99941444, 0.031748302;
 -0.0010082112, -0.031763725, 0.99949491]
Camera #3:
K:
[8439.012955389799, 0, 447;
 0, 8439.012955389799, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[1, 8.6602086e-09, 4.6566129e-10;
 -6.2404979e-09, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]
Camera #4:
K:
[8518.394954182764, 0, 447;
 0, 8518.394954182764, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[0.99987215, -0.015882459, -0.0018503442;
 0.015817553, 0.99939477, -0.030980414;
 0.0023412704, 0.030947186, 0.99951828]
Camera #5:
K:
[8491.398203106019, 0, 447;
 0, 8491.398203106019, 335.5;
 0, 0, 1]
R:
[0.99940926, -0.034253821, -0.0027813595;
 0.034020044, 0.99755055, -0.061118517;
 0.0048680915, 0.060987789, 0.99812663]
Warping images (auxiliary)...
Warping images, time: 0.0660702 sec
Compositing...
Compositing image #2
Multi-band blender, number of bands: 10
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS) in cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map, file G:\Development\opencv\sources\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 4773
```

All suggestions greatly appreciated, as I'm new to C++ and OpenCV.

Thanks

**Update**

After disabling OpenCL, I get the following error:

```
Compositing...
Compositing image #2
Multi-band blender, number of bands: 10
Compositing image #3
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.cols < SHRT_MAX && dst.rows < SHRT_MAX && src.cols < SHRT_MAX && src.rows < SHRT_MAX) in cv::remap, file G:\Development\opencv\sources\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 4956
```

Comment: There is an issue with GPU Mat allocation for some graphic cards (my guess is that you have some sort of intel card) in opencv, which makes stitching_detailed.cpp example "a bit" unstable. You can disable GPU in runtime with cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false); command, which would solve the problem, but computation would require a bit more time. You should be aware of stitching with OpenCV, because it is very unstable when focus is not correctly estimated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm actually using an Nvidia GTX 780 Ti, and I honestly would doubt there's an issue like this with that card. Where would I use the `cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false);` command? I tried including it at the top of the `main` method, but the namespace `ocl` doesn't exist.

Comment: Integration of CUDA and OpenCV is ongoing process, so we can expect some improvements I hope. Using command at the top of the main is okey, you just need to include header for that ;) I think it is #include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

Comment: BTW you can consider using http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#Stitcher class, which has use_gpu option and see if it works fine. You should also look into difference between Stitcher class implementation and stitching_detailed.cpp, think you can find better parameters set up there & some hints of how to make things work better.

Comment: Thanks again Dmitrii. I've now disabled OpenCL but got another error (see my OP). Do you know of any other good stitching software/libraries?

Comment: None that would be decent unfortunately, I ended up with making hotfixes in opencv's logic, but it was a commercial project. Now to your error: assertion says that destination size of your panorama is higher that SHRT_MAX, which is a hell of a lot if we consider that you only have 3 images. What is the size of your input images? Can you show your images? Can you try the code with same images but resize them first (say to 800x*** each one)?

Comment: The five images were 4000x3000 pixels each! I can resize for testing purposes, but I assume there's an easy way to increase the max size of the images?

Comment: Short max is 0x7FFF, so I guess that if homography was found incorrectly - you could've reached the max value. You should try resizing them for test purposes. If you really want to use images that big of the size - you can change result Mat type from short to something else. For example, search for CV_16S and try to replace it with CV_32S. However you might face a problem, where opencv's internal function would not work with CV_32S Mats, no way to predict that, try and see the result

Comment: Have you succeed with smaller images?